# Provider don't update widget on IIS, only in VSCode server, in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, iis, deployment, flutter-provider

i'm making a e-commerce app with Android and Web Flutter, but, when i deploy the web app in IIS, a widget don't update. When i run on VSCode, they work as well. Android work's.
The trouble is only in Iis web Flutter. The data change, but not the widget.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, Need more information to troubleshoot your issue, did you get any error messages?

Comment: No, no error messages :(

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this messages, I suggest you open a case via: support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the bug isn't in IIS, i created a new provider for the action and all runs ok.